# Align ListTile Icon to Left

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to align an icon before the title using a ListTile?
I know that trailing aligns the icon after the title.
Is there a reverse way?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`leading` property is what you are looking for:

```
  ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
         ...
      )
```

Refer to this documentation [ListTile-leading](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile/leading.html)

Comment: There is one issue about this solution, it is that the margin of the title to the leading is assigned automatically. How could it be changed?

Answer (score 4):

`leading` and `trailing` properties can be used on both sides.

```
ListTile(
    leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app_outlined), // for Right
    trailing: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app_outlined) // for Left
  )
```